# Intersection between $2$ lines (3D). This doesn't have a solution does it?

Tags: linear-algebra, 3d, vectors

so I was looking through an old exam and this question was given:
[image: question]

The teachers answer was the point $(9, -9, 21)$

I tried solving this myself, I got $x = x$, $y = y$, but I could not find a point where all coordinates were equal on both lines.

At the point the teacher gave, the $z$ coordinates seem to not be equal for both lines. I'm asking this since I want to be sure because a teacher made this question/solution.

So my question is:
Does the question not have a valid real solution?

Comment: The teacher's answer lies on $L_1$ but not on $L_2$.

Comment: Thank you for verifying, seems there is no real point of intersection between these two lines.

Comment: That's right.${}$